# $(2x+2)(2x+2)=(2x+2)(5x^3+2x+2)$ in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> In $\mathbb Z_{10}[x], (2x+2)(2x+2)=(2x+2)(5x^3+2x+2)$ yet $(2x+2)$ cannot be cancelled in this equation. Why is this possible in $\mathbb Z_{10}[x]$ and not $\mathbb Z_5[x]$?

So $(2x+2)(2x+2)=4x^2+8x+4$ and $(2x+2)(5x^3+2x+2)=10x^4+10x^3+4x^2+8x+4$.

Now I see that $10x^4+10x^3+(4x^2+8x+4)=10x^4+10x^3+(2x+2)(2x+2)$ and in $\mathbb Z_{10}[x], 10x^4+10x^3+(2x+2)(2x+2)=(2x+2)(2x+2)$.

But wouldn't, in $\mathbb Z_5[x], 10x^4+10x^3+(2x+2)(2x+2)=(2x+2)(2x+2)$?

Answer (score 0):

Cancellation is equivalent to having inverse i.e. you can cancel $a$ from equation $ab=ac$ only if $a$ has an inverse. If you are familiar with ring theory, you will see that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field and $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is not. Thus in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ you can cancell because in fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ you have inverse of $2x+2$ which is $3/(x+1)$, while these can not happen for $\mathbb{Z}_{10}[x]$.

Comment: so even though in $\mathbb Z_{10}[x]$, $10x^4=0\cdot x^4$ I cannot cancel?

Comment: That's it. The number $10$ has no inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. But you may cancel $x^4$, since you reach a correct equation $10=0$.

Comment: Oh so I cannot cancel in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ then? $10x^4=0\cdot x^4$ in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$

Comment: No, again $10$ is not invertable in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: Even though $10=5 \cdot 2$? This is where I am stumped. In $\mathbb Z_5$ I thought any multiple of $5\equiv 0$?

Comment: You got it now. Note that in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ you have this equality: $$2x+2=12345x^{2017}+347x+98767 $$ because of congruent modulo $5$.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm thick headed. I don't understand why it is assumed that we can cancel $2x+2$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ then? Obviously, if we're in modulo $10$ then we'd still have $2x+2$, the same as in modulo 5

Comment: $2$ is a zero-divisor in $\mathbb Z_{10}$, i.e. there is $a \ne 0$ (namely $5$) such that $2a = 0$.  It is not a zero-divisor in $\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: Cancellation is not equivalent to having an inverse. Cancellation is equivalent to not being a zero divisor.